# sourcing setup.bash does not work in galactic

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

So I installed ros2 galactic using the installation instructions, but when I use `source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash` it does not work, e.g. `ros2` command is not found. That being said, when I use `. ~/ros2_galactic/ros2-linux/setup.bash` (mentioned in the installation instructions), it does do what it's supposed to do. Please help me!

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387917/sourcing-setup.bash-does-not-work-in-galactic/) by [feri73](https://answers.ros.org/users/86424/feri73/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-10-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2021-10-04**:
Which installation instructions did you follow?

**Comment by [feri73](https://answers.ros.org/users/86424/feri73/) on 2021-10-04**:
this one: https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Binary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the instructions you followed say, when installing from a pre-built binary tarball you have to use `source ~/ros2_galactic/ros2-linux/setup.bash` to activate ROS. It has been installed to `~/ros2_galactic`. If you want it installed in `/opt/ros` then you need to follow [these instructions](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html) to install using Debian packages. This works on Ubuntu, despite the name of the package format.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1